# mod_rewrite - Removing index.php from URL (in subfolder)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get an API working (locally, for now), which lives in a subfolder. I've been trying every example I can find, but all are ending up in 404 errors.

I have this URL:
`http://127.0.0.1/~owner/personal/api/v1/index.php/tasks`

I want to be able to use this:
`http://127.0.0.1/~owner/personal/api/v1/tasks`

Eventually, it will become this:
`http://api.mydomain.com/tasks`

I just can't seem to get my .htaccess rules setup correctly. This keeps getting suggested, but does nothing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

What am I missing?

---

**Update**

I have setup my virtual hosts to use `http://api.local/` instead of the previously used addresses.

Accessing `http://api.local/index.php/tasks` works.

Accessing `http://api.local/tasks` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Maybe** part of your problem is your development environment. You are using a local server to do this on with several subfolders deep and I think it's messing with your .htaccess depending on the location.

If your `.htaccess` is in the root of your website `http://127.0.0.1/.htaccess` then it's not going to work properly.

Make sure it's in the same directory as your `index.php` file and make sure `/~owner/personal/api/v1/` is your `document root` for your dev environment as specified in your apache config file.

Then you can test out your htaccess rules and see how they work. Your current rule should be ok providing `/tasks` won't be a real directory in the root.

On another note,

I always suggest using your real domain name so you could see how it works as if it were in production. You can do that by modifying your `HOST` file on your PC and the site will only available to you and `you` can access via yoursite.com. This quick [easy guide](http://my.kualo.com/knowledgebase/1101-using-the-hosts-file-to-test-or-develop-a-website.html) will show you.

Try specifying the rewrite base.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I don't know why this didn't occur to me earlier. I have setup a virtual host on my machine, and am now pointing at http://api.local/ instead of the address being used earlier. I am still unable to get the rewrite rules to work, though, and the api is insisting on having the /index.php/ in there. The /v1 folder is set as root, and the .htaccess file is in there. No luck, though.

Comment: I just noticed the first part of your answer... Yes, it would end up being `http://api.local/.htaccess`... How does that change the rewrite rules in this case?

Comment: Hmm, It shouldn't be needed but maybe try specifying the rewritebase. See my example in the update.

Comment: Thank you, it's finally working. .htaccess has always been a pain for me. I'm glad you were able to help nail this down.

Comment: Been there before. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the parameters of `RewriteRule` backwards. You need this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)/index.php(.+)?$ /$1$2
```

This means:

- if it's not a file
- and it's not a directory
- and it looks like `/` (optional), possibly some more characters, then `/index.php`, then possibly some more characters, go to the URL without the `/index.php` part.

Note that I deleted the `[L]` for now -- it means "if the URL matches this rule, don't apply any more rules." You say you want to keep transforming it into `http://api.mydomain.com/tasks`, so you shouldn't use `[L]`.

Comment: This seemed promising, but didn't work, unfortunately